# removing duplicate code cause redundant operation?

Tags: c, refactoring

```
void caller()
{
    int var;

    var = setvar();
    if (var == 1)
        func1();
    else if (var == 3)
        func3();
    else if (var == 8)
        func8();
}

void func1()
{
    common();
    //do something case 1 specific...
}

void func3()
{
    common();
    //do something case 3 specific...
}

void func8()
{
    common();
    //do something case 8 specific...
}
```

In this case, I feel very uncomfortable because I have duplicate function *common()* which could be written inside the *caller()* function to remove duplicate. So I can change above code like this:

```
void caller()
{
    int var;

    var = setvar();
    if (var == 1 || var == 3 || var == 8)
        common();
    if (var == 1)
        func1();
    else if (var == 3)
        func3();
    else if (var == 8)
        func8();
}

void func1()
{ //do something case 1 specific... }

void func3()
{ //do something case 3 specific... }

void func8()
{ //do something case 8 specific... }
```

However, I feel very uncomfortable in this case too, because *caller()* function now check *var*'s value twice.

I don't have much experience of coding, so I don't know what to consider to choose which one is better. What is better code and why? What do I have to consider?

Comment: I would go with the first variant. There is nothing wrong in having a common code in different functions, as long as it is separated into a function by itself.

Comment: Does it make more sense for `caller` to call `common`, or should only `funcX` know about the call?  Encapsulation means limiting actions to only the required scope.

Comment: As Eugene Sh. already has mentioned, there is nothing wrong. Please don't overthink and please don't make your code more worse. Your initial approach is totally fine and every other solution doesn't make it better. What you could try is to maybe combine func1, func3 and func8, maybe there is some more potential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `common` is only meant to be called by `func1`, `func3`, and `func8`, then the first option is better - there's no reason for `caller` to know about `common`, much less call it directly.

Ideally, `caller` should not care what `func1`, `func3`, and `func8` do internally; it should only care about what parameters they take and what values they return.  Suppose you need to add another function (we'll call it `func5`).  Does it need to call `common` as well?  Or does it not?  What if you need to change the behavior of `func3` so that it no longer calls `common` at all?

With the first option, you're localizing the knowledge about `common` to the functions that actually use it, which will make maintenance and debugging easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the second approach.

First I would improve this code by separating the validation function (improves debugging) and using switch case to determine what function to run based on value of `var`.

Pros:

- You can keep track with ease of where the function `common()` is used just by looking to the `isAllowed` numbers.
- Don't need to write `common()` within every single function you use it. It'd be redundant if you use it in hundreds of func's and you might forget one.
- Easily visualize when `common()` will be applied

Cons:

- You have to add or remove cases in switch/case (use if/else wheter you prefer) depending on the isAllowed defined integers. It may lead to fire `default` if you forgot to add a case or if a bug happen.
- You double check the var's value.

```
int isAllowed(int var){
    return var == 1 || var == 3 || var == 8;
}

void caller()
{
    int var = setVar();
    if (isAllowed(var)){
        common();
        switch(var){
            case 1:
                func1();
                break;
            case 3:
                func3();
                break;
            case 8:
                func8();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What? Don't do this, this is awful.

Comment: so you mean you prefer call common() once in caller() because it is more easy to understand what's being done?

Comment: @kjh1918 your very top approach is totally okay and fine to read. Everyone will understand this code. Don't overthink. Should your code maybe too much redundant, your compiler will optimize it anyway. A good readability of code is much more worth.

Comment: There may be another approach
 (those breaks, I know they're not like javascript), but I personally can easily understand. Also, you should suggest something else before criticizing

Comment: @testing_22 I've no problem with your switch, but with your _isAllowed_ function, as it hides information.

Comment: What you suggest? I have to point out that in this case ```default``` is not necessary, but if you change isAllowed it may cause problems since it won't match any statement

Comment: I suggest to not overthink and to use the very first solution of OP, cause that's the best solution in my eyes.

Comment: Fine! So just elaborate your answer and explain your points of view, here's not the appropriate space to do so

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function pointer:

```
void caller()
{
    int var = setvar();
    void (*func)() = NULL;

    if (var == 1)
        func = func1;
    else if (var == 3)
        func = func3;
    else if (var == 8)
        func = func8;
    else return; // or error handling

    common();
    func();
}
```

If a special common is used for a specific case, then one could use two function pointer, one for `common` part another one for `func` part.

```
void caller()
{
    int var = setvar();
    void (*func)() = NULL;
    void (*fcommon)() = common; // default common

    if (var == 1) {
        func = func1;
    } else if (var == 3) {
        func = func3;
    } else if (var == 8) {
        fcommon = common_for_8;
        func = func8;
    } else {
        return; // or error handling
    }

    fcommon();
    func();
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is justified enough in this case. Also these functions do not have to be of the same type (yes I know in this abstract example they are)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Maybe, but it checks conditions once, and moves `common()` outside of `funcN()` helpers, and it is quite concise code.

Comment: is this approach can be applied to some situations that caller() have to consider some other cases that don't do common()?

Comment: @kjh1918, in such a case `common()` would not be ... common

Comment: yes, maybe common_for_138()? but i do care such a case.

Comment: @kjh1918, you could use two function pointers, one for `common()` another one for `funcN()`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how to do with two function pointers. Can you write example code? Thank you.

Comment: @tstanisl Thank you very much, but I think John Bode's answer is more appropriate for what i was wondering. I'm sorry.